# Get data from the Database using ADO.NET in razor pages

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, ado.net, razor-pages

When I try to search in the URL for an employee who doesn't exist, the URL returns a positive response as if it were finding an employee after an `id` that doesn't exist in the database, but it's empty instead of redirecting me to the `NotFound` page. Here is the code that retrieves data from the database:

```
public Employee GetEmployeeData(int? id)
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblEmployee WHERE EmployeeID= " + id;
            SqlCommand commend = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection);

            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader readData = commend.ExecuteReader();

            while (readData.Read())
            {
                employee.Id = Convert.ToInt32(readData["EmployeeID"]);
                employee.Name = readData["Name"].ToString();
                employee.Gender = readData["Gender"].ToString();
                employee.Department = readData["Department"].ToString();
                employee.City = readData["City"].ToString();
            }
        }
        return employee;
    }
```

Here is the `OnGet` and `OnPost` methods from my `EditEmployee.cshmtl.cs`:

```
 public ActionResult OnGet(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("/NotFound");
        }
        Employee = objemployee.GetEmployeeData(id);

        if (Employee == null)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("/NotFound");
        }
        return Page();
    }
    public ActionResult OnPost()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }
        objemployee.UpdateEmployee(Employee);

        return RedirectToPage("./EmployeeIndex");
    }
```

When I go to the Edit page and try to change the `id` in the URL, the answer is not null for any `int` but is empty. Here is the link where I made the tutorial with some small changes [enter link description here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/razor-page-web-application-with-asp-net-core-using-ado-net/)

Here is the image and that's my problem. I wrote in the URL an id that does not exist in my database, but it still returns a null and empty id.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC9yx.png

Some ideas, please?

Comment: This happens because Empoyee is never null. Do you see the line where you create a new Employee?. Well that empty employee is returned if there are no records

Comment: The issue is related to the GetEmployeeData method, even if the database doesn't contain the especial Employee, it still return a new Employee instance. As Saravanan said, try to check if the Employee exists first, then return a new Employee instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should return null on failure to get the data, instead you are returning a new instance of `Employee` always.
Try the below code change

```
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblEmployee WHERE EmployeeID= " + id;
        SqlCommand commend = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection);
    
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader readData = commend.ExecuteReader();
        
        if(!readData.HasRows) return null;
    
        Employee employee = new Employee();
    
        while (readData.Read())
        {
            employee.Id = Convert.ToInt32(readData["EmployeeID"]);
            employee.Name = readData["Name"].ToString();
            employee.Gender = readData["Gender"].ToString();
            employee.Department = readData["Department"].ToString();
            employee.City = readData["City"].ToString();
        }
        return employee;
    }
```

Comment: @Steve, yes, forgot to check if no rows are found and return null